# How to downgrade package using ansible

Tags: ansible, apt

My ansible file looks like this:

```
- name: hold docker-ce release
  copy:
    dest: /etc/apt/preferences.d/docker-ce
    content: |
      Package: docker-ce
      Pin: version 5:18.09.7~3-0~ubuntu-xenial
      Pin-Priority: 1002

- name: install docker-ce
  apt:
    name: docker-ce
    update_cache: yes
```

My target system currently has `docker-ce=5:19.03.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial` installed. With the `preferences.d/docker-ce` file present, when I run

`apt install docker-ce`

It correctly tells me that it will downgrade (in accordance with the preferences file):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  docker-ce
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to downgrade, 0 to remove and 10 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/17.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 23.2 MB disk space will be freed.
```

However when I run ansible, this is the output:

```
TASK [docker_host : hold docker-ce release] *******
ok: [myhost.com]

TASK [docker_host : ensure docker is installed] ***
ok: [myhost.com]
```

And the ansible script fails to downgrade the version of docker-ce to the version specified in `preferences.d/docker-ce`

How do I get ansible to run the equivalent of

`apt install docker-ce`

So that I can be sure my systems are configured according to my ansible file?